# Conditions for embedding between non-oriented graphs

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

I have the following assignment on my Algorithms Analysis course.
Given two undirected graphs $G_1 = (V_1, E_1)$ and $G_2 = (V_2, E_2)$ with $\operatorname{card} (V_1) < \operatorname{card} (V_2)$ and $\operatorname{card} (E_1) < \operatorname{card} (E_2)$, is the graph $G_1$ isomorphic with a subgraph of $G_2$? The proof must be based on a non-deterministic algorithm.

Comment: To clarify - you need to prove that the problem is in NP?

Comment: Yes, the main statement is: "prove that this problem is in NP"

Comment: so I guess you didn't understand what NP means and what it is useful for ?

Comment: As it is formulated now, the question seems to ask either for a proof that $G_1$ can be embedded in $G_2$. Why not reformulate it?

Comment: I wrote here the statement of the problem exactly as our teacher gave it to us

Answer (score 2):

Pick, non-deterministicly, an injection $f:V_1 \to V_2$ (in other words, pick, once and for all, a numbering of the vertices of $G_1$, and pick, non-deterministically, an ordered list of $|V_1|$ elements from $V_2$). Check whether this is an isomorphism onto its image subgraph. If not, pick another injection. Rinse and repeat.

The isomorphism check is naively linear in $|E_1|\cdot |E_2| < |V_1|^2 \cdot |V_2|^2$: For every pair $(e_1, e_2)$ with $e_1 \in E_1, e_2 \in E_2$, see whether the end points of $e_1$ are sent to the endpoints of $e_2$ by $f$. There are $|E_1| \cdot |E_2|$ such pairs. The check is therefore polynomial time, and thus the whole algorithm is $NP$.

Comment: Why do you need to pick another injection if the first fails?  Isn't it enough to just pick one injection, and accept iff it is an isomorphism?

Comment: @cardboard_box The injection essentially picks _one_ subgraph of $G_2$ with the right number of vertices. We are asked to tell whether there are _any_ subgraphs of $G_2$ that are isomorphic to $G_1$. so just because the first one we picked happened to be non-isomorphic doesn't mean that none of the others are.

Comment: But the entire point of non-deterministic algorithms is that if *any* possible valid path of computation accepts, then the algorithm accepts.  So you can assume that the non-deterministic choices are always the "correct" ones.

Comment: @cardboard_box No, the point of non-deterministic polynomial time algorithms is that if the non-determinacy is _lucky_, then the algorithm runs in polynomial time. For instance, the NP-decision problem called the Travelling Salesman Problem asks whether there are any paths he can take that are shorter than some $N$. The classic non-deterministic algorithm to solve it is to randomly pick a path (of which there are many), calculate the length (which is easy), and if it fails, check another path. You don't say "There are no paths shorter than $N$" just because the first path was longer.

Comment: That's not the definition of non-determinism I learned.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-deterministic_Turing_machine#Resolution_of_multiple_rules) seems to agree with me.  (Though both definitions are equivalent in terms of the complexity classes they produce).

Comment: @cardboard_box If you read what you just linked, it says 'that the machine is the "luckiest possible guesser"'. I am assuming that the machine my algorithm is implemented on is a machine with a good random number generator and normal luck. It seems like pot-eh-to, pot-ah-to to me in the end.